# If $g(y)=\max\limits_{x \in X} f(x,y)=f(h(y),y).$ Prove that $h(y)$ is continuous

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, multivariable-calculus

Let $ X\subset\mathbb{R}^m$ and $Y\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ non empty, convex and compact sets, and let $f : X\times Y\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ continuous funtion.
If

$f(\cdot,y):Y\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ convex for every $y\in Y$
$f(x,\cdot):X\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ concave for every $x\in X$

If $g(y)=\max\limits_{x \in X} f(x,y)=f(h(y),y).$

Prove that

$\cdot \quad g(y)$ is continuous

My attempt.

Proof:

Suppose g(y) is not continuous. So

there exist $ \epsilon>0$ and  a sequence $\{y_i\}\subseteq Y$ : $ y_i \rightarrow y_0 \in Y$,such that $\Vert g(y_i)-g(y_0)\Vert>\varepsilon$  for every $i$.
and for the function $f(h(y).\cdot)$ :

$|f(h(y_i),y_0)-f(h(y_0),y_0)|>\delta,\quad i=1,2,...$

we subtract and add $f(h(y_0),y_i)$:

$\delta < |f(h(y_i),y_0)-f(h(y_0),y_0)+f(h(y_0),y_i)-f(h(y_0),y_i)|$

$ = |f(h(y_i),y_0)-f(h(y_0),y_i)+f(h(y_0),y_i)-f(h(y_0),y_0)|$

$\leq |f(h(y_i),y_0)-f(h(y_i),y_0)|+ |f(h(y_0),y_i)-f(h(y_0),y_0)|$

I'm not sure if this the correct way of proving it.

I suppose i could try applying that f is continuous on a compact set.

Comment: There are no assumptions on $g$? Is $g$ even used?

Comment: How is $h(y)$ defined??? There is nothing above that suggests the $\operatorname{argmax}$ is unique.

Comment: you're correct , i meant prove g(y) is continious

Comment: One cheap way is to notice that $g$ is convex and defined on $\mathbb{R}^m$ hence continuous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a special case of the [maximum theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_theorem).
Nevertheless, we can prove it with weaker arguments.
The below does not use any of the presumed convexity, relying only on compactness and continuity.

Let $(y_{n})_{n}$ be a sequence converging in $Y$ to some point $\hat{y}$.
Since $Y$ is compact, this point is in $Y$.
Next, pick $(x_{n})_{n}$ such that
$$
f(x_{n},y_{n})=\max_{x}f(x,y_{n}).
$$
Since $X$ is compact, we can pick a subsequence along which $x_{n}$ converges.
Therefore, w.l.o.g., suppose $x_{n}$ converges to a point $\hat{x}$.
We claim that $\max_{x}f(x,\hat{y})=f(\hat{x},\hat{y})$.
In this case,
$$
g(y_{n})-g(\hat{y})=f(x_{n},y_{n})-f(\hat{x},\hat{y})\rightarrow0
$$
and hence $g$ is continuous, as desired.

Let us return to the unproved claim of the previous paragraph.
Let $x$ be arbitrary.
Then,
$$
f(\hat{x},\hat{y})=\lim_{n}f(x_{n},y_{n})\geq\lim_{n}f(x,y_{n})=f(x,\hat{y}).
$$
Since $x$ was arbitrary, it follows that $f(\hat{x},\hat{y})\geq\max_{x}f(x,\hat{y})$.
The reverse inequality is trivial.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $y_k \to y$. We could like to show that $g(y_k) \to g(y)$.

Here is a terse proof. It relies on the result that $z_k \to z$ **iff** for all subsequences $K \subset \mathbb{N}$ there exists a further subsequence $K' \subset K$ such that $z_k \overset{K'}{\rightarrow}z$

Since $X$ is compact, there are $x_k$ such that $f(x_k,y_k) = g(y_k)$.

Pick a subsequence $K$. Then there is some $K' \subset K$ and $x' \in X$ such that $x_k \overset{K'}{\rightarrow}x'$. Then we have (i) $g(y_k)=f(x_k,y_k) \overset{K'}{\rightarrow} f(x',y)$ and (ii) since $f(x,y_k) \le f(x_k,y_k)$ for all $k$ and $x$, taking limits gives $f(x,y) \le f(x',y)$ for all $x$ and hence $g(y) = f(x',y)$ and so $g(y_k) \overset{K'}{\rightarrow}g(y)$.

Consequently $g(y_k) \to g(y)$ as required.